# New SubDomain Config for Nginx Throwing an Error: [crit] 29036#0

Tags: wordpress, nginx, subdomain

I have (1) domain and two paths configured:
    mysite.com
    blog.mysite.com

I'm trying to configure a `wordpress` blog on my existing `mysite.com` nginx server,

**mysite.com** has a `sites-enabled` config of:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name     *.mysite.com;
        root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/mysite/myapp/;

        access_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/error/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/error/error.log warn;
        connection_pool_size 2048;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;

        location /static {
            alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/mysite/myapp/static/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_read_timeout 10;
            proxy_connect_timeout 10;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

**blog.mysite.com** has a `sites-enabled` config of:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name     blog.mysite.com;
        root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/blog;
        index index.php;

        #### errors
        access_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/blog/error/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/blog/error/error.log warn;
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;

        #### locations

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

    }
```

the `error.log` file in `blog.mysite.com` is showing an error of:

```
2014/01/02 02:50:05 [crit] 29036#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: blog.mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "blog.mysite.com"
```

Anyone know why this isn't working? I tried some research, but can't seem to find the solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone run's into this error when trying to add a subdomain or domain while configuring nginx with phpfm - follow the steps in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/114076/ubuntu-php5-fpm-unix-socket

The gist:
sudo vim /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf.

Look for the line listen = 127.0.0.1:9000 and change it to something like listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock. After doing so, restart PHP FPM:

sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not really related to subdomains, you just didn't use the right configuration, your fpm was listening to a port instead of a sock file, it wouldn't have worked even without the subdomain,

your main site was working because it was passing to port 8001

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
```

Your subdomain could have worked if you passed to port 9000

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
```

But the way you fixed it is better, using sock files is better than port.

Just wanted to explain that it wasn't because of the subdomain.